# Flutter ERROR: NDEF tag does not contain any NDEF message on ios

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, nfc, ndef

I tried to build an NFC App and it works still fine - beside one big problem. When I want to describe a newly purchased NFC tag with my app, this does not work with the error code:
ERROR: NDEF tag does not contain any NDEF message.
However, if I open another NFC app from the AppStore, it works perfectly with the tag.
It is also strange that once I have written a text to the tag with another NFC App, my app now works perfectly and I can now write to the tag.

So my question is, why can I only write NFC tags with my app that already contain a message?

I would also be interested to know how I could programme my app so that it can also write to empty tags. Since this also works with the other app from the AppStore, it must be possible with iOS.

Many thanks in advance to all those who take the time to deal with my question.

```js
Future<void> writeToTag()async{
  try {

    final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');

    if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
      

      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
            title: const Text("Halten Sie Ihr Gerät an den Chip, den Sie lesen                  möchten"),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: const Text("Cancel"),
                onPressed: () {
                  _stream?.cancel();
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }



      List <NDEFRecord> my = [NDEFRecord.type("Chip", _random)];
      NDEFMessage Message = NDEFMessage.withRecords(my);

      await NFC.writeNDEF(Message, once: true).first;
      funktinoiert.year = true;

      setState(() {
        isloading = true;
      });

      int time = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;


      Map<String, dynamic> data = {
        "random" : _random,
        "Time" : time,
      };

      await Firestore.instance
          .collection("NFC")
          .document(_random)
          .setData(data)
          .catchError((e) {
        funktinoiert.year = false;
        print(e);
      });

      await Firestore.instance
          .collection("Anzahl")
          .document("Prototyp")
          .updateData({"NFC": FieldValue.increment(1)})
          .catchError((e) {
        print(e);
      });
    }

  }
  on FirebaseException catch (e) {
    newEntryFehlermeldung("$e \n\n Bitte versuchen Sie es erneut. Sollten Sie den Fehler nicht beheben können hilft unser Team Ihnen gerne weiter.");
    funktinoiert.year = false;
  } on PlatformException {
    newEntryFehlermeldung("Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten, bitte versuchen Sie es erneut");
    funktinoiert.year = false;
  } on NFCUserCanceledSessionException {
    funktinoiert.year = false;
    return null;
  } on NFCSessionTerminatedUnexpectedlyException {
    newEntryFehlermeldung("Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten, bitte versuchen Sie es erneut");
    funktinoiert.year = false;
  } on NFCSessionTimeoutException {
    newEntryFehlermeldung("Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten, bitte versuchen Sie es erneut");
    funktinoiert.year = false;
  } on NFCTagNotWritableException {
    newEntryFehlermeldung("Es sieht so aus, als wäre der Chip nicht beschreibbar. Bitte versuchen Sie es erneut.");
    funktinoiert.year = false;
  } on NFCTagSizeTooSmallException {
    newEntryFehlermeldung("Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten, bitte versuchen Sie es erneut");
    funktinoiert.year = false;
  } on NFCTagUnwritableException {
    newEntryFehlermeldung("Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten, bitte versuchen Sie es erneut");
    funktinoiert.year = false;
  } on NFCTagUnavailableException {
    newEntryFehlermeldung("Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten, bitte versuchen Sie es erneut");
    funktinoiert.year = false;
  } on NFCSystemIsBusyException {
    newEntryFehlermeldung("Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten, bitte versuchen Sie es erneut");
    funktinoiert.year = false;
  } on Exception catch (exception) {
    newEntryFehlermeldung("$exception \n\n Bitte versuchen Sie es erneut. Sollten Sie den Fehler nicht beheben können hilft unser Team Ihnen gerne weiter.");
    funktinoiert.year = false;
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/home");
    print(exception);
  } catch (e) {
    funktinoiert.year = false;
    newEntryFehlermeldung("Es besteht keine Verbindung zum Internet. Bitte versuchen Sie es erneut. Sollten Sie den Fehler nicht beheben können hilft unser Team Ihnen gerne weiter.");
  }


  if(funktinoiert.year == true){
    newEntry();
    funktinoiert.year = false;
  } else{
    newEntryFehlermeldung("Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten, bitte versuchen Sie es erneut");
  }


  setState(() {
    isloading = false;
  });

  Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/home");
}
```

Comment: What is the NFC Tag make and model?

Comment: It's a  NXP NTAG210μ, https://www.shopnfc.com/de/transparente-nfc-stickers/245-nfc-stickers-ntag210-14x21mm.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok that Tag comes from the Factory already formatted for NDef (which means as it is a Type 2 Tag that if has a Capability container and contains an Empty Ndef Message TLV block)

The problem is the combination of what I would say is the flutter plugin not working around a bug in iOS (so also a bug in the plugin).

The problem is the plugin only asks iOS get notified when a Tag with containing a NDEF message which iOS interprets this as an NDEF message with a payload data of greater than 0 bytes where as the NFC Specification for this type of Tag says detection includes a Zero length NDEF messages.

How other iOS apps work is they are probably native Apps that work around this iOS bug by asking iOS to be notified when any Type of Tag comes in to range and then check to see if it is Ndef capable before writing an non empty NDef message to them.

How to fix it for you is difficult, try some of the other NFC flutter plugins or write you own.

I would at least raise a bug/feature request for the NFC flutter plugin to get it to handle this situation.

For iOS this probably comes from when it could only read NDef messages and could not write them as NFC support in iOS is poor.

Comment: Thank you Andrew - I wrote a request for the plugin. But you have no idea how I can solve this problem with this plugin?

Comment: I don't think it is solvable just using this plugin, the plugin design is based on the iOS API's that were designed when iOS could only read existing Ndef messages and therefore did not care about zero length Ndef messages as there is nothing to read in it (but zero length Ndef messages are important when you want to write to new Tags or reformatted tags)

Comment: All right, too bad, but thank you very much! Can you recommend a good nfc package from your experience?